# How do you properly implement async search results?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I made a clone of UITableView called **TableView** with its own dataSource and delegate that mimics the original UITableView but is intended to do some things differently. I also made a **GoogleSuggest** class with its own delegate that requests google autocomplete suggestions from a known URL.

The **GoogleSuggest** class has this method:

```
- (void)requestSuggestionsForText:(NSString *)text {

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(asyncRequestSuggestionsForText:)
                             toTarget:self
                           withObject:text];
}
```

When called it dispatches this private background thread:

```
- (void)asyncRequestSuggestionsForText:(NSString *)text;
```

When it receives results it calls this delegate method:

```
- (void)googleSuggestDidReceiveResult:(GoogleSuggestResult *)result;
```

Everything worked fine with little controlled experiments until I put it all together in the main **ViewController**.

Initially, this method returned a "**UI API called on a background thread**" error:

```
#pragma mark - GoogleSuggestDelegate

- (void)googleSuggestDidReceiveResult:(GoogleSuggestResult *)result {
    
    _googleSuggestions = result.suggestions;

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Then I replaced the last line with this and it worked:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Now, I'm getting a "**-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbbe7252cd9143595**" error.

The **result.suggestions** is a simple **NSMutableArray** with **NSString** variables, no NSNumbers anywhere.

**This works and I get to see all results logged:**

```
- (TableViewCell *)tableView:(tableView *)tableView cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    
    TableViewCell *cellView = [[TableViewCell alloc] init];
    
    NSString *result = [_googleSuggestions objectAtIndex:index];
            
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
            
    // cellView.titleLabel.text = result;
    
    return cellView;
}
```

**This also works and I get to see all results logged:**

```
- (TableViewCell *)tableView:(tableView *)tableView cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    
    TableViewCell *cellView = [[TableViewCell alloc] init];
    
    NSString *result = [_googleSuggestions objectAtIndex:index];
            
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
            
    cellView.titleLabel.text = @"example text";
    
    return cellView;
}
```

**This fails when I try to assign the result to the titleLabel.text:**

```
- (TableViewCell *)tableView:(tableView *)tableView cellAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    
    TableViewCell *cellView = [[TableViewCell alloc] init];
    
    NSString *result = [_googleSuggestions objectAtIndex:index];
            
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
            
    cellView.titleLabel.text = result;
    
    return cellView;
}
```

It makes no sense, it's clearly an NSString variable assigned to an object that has no problem with NSString variables like shown in the working examples above.

*How do you properly implement async search results?*

*How do you properly update UI elements from a background thread?*

Comment: "How do you properly update UI elements from a background thread" You don't. You step out to the main thread (typically using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue` as you have it).

Comment: Why would I possibly get this random NSNumber error then?

Comment: You're not giving anywhere near enough information to answer that question. You're the one logging, you're the one who has the app and the debugger. Debug. But I can tell you this: the fact that you are trying to access googleSuggestions from two different threads is a Very Bad Smell.